# How to use findByxxx in our custom repository

Tags: rest, spring-data

I want to use findByHostObjectId to query MyEnity, but it says "**No property hostObjectId found for type MyEntity**"

I have my Rest Controller and **@autowired** MyRepository and I want to use MyRepository.findByHostObjectId(hostObjectId) to get MyEntity by request parameter(hostObjectId).

Repository

```
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityId> {
//success 
MyEntity findById(@Param("id") MyEntityId id);

//fail
MyEntity findByHostObjectId(@Param("hostObjectId") Integer hostObjectId);}
```

MyEntity

```
public class MyEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

private MyEntityId id;

public MyEntity() {
}

public MyEntity(MyEntityId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@EmbeddedId
public MyEntityId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(MyEntityId id) {
    this.id = id;
}}
```

MyEntityId

```
@Embeddable
public class MyEntityId implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int objectId;
private Integer hostObjectId;
private String hostName;

public MyEntityId() {
}

public MyEntityId(int objectId, Integer hostObjectId, String hostName) {
    this.objectId = objectId;
    this.hostObjectId = hostObjectId;
    this.hostName = hostName;
}

public int getObjectId() {
    return this.objectId;
}

public void setObjectId(int objectId) {
    this.objectId = objectId;
}

public Integer getHostObjectId() {
    return this.hostObjectId;
}

public void setHostObjectId(Integer hostObjectId) {
    this.hostObjectId = hostObjectId;
}

public String getHostName() {
    return this.hostName;
}

public void setHostName(String hostName) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
}}
```

MyEntiry.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="sud.MyEntity" table="sud_view_myentity">
    <composite-id name="id" class="sud.MyEntityId">
        <key-property name="objectId" type="int">
             <column name="OBJECT_ID" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="hostObjectId" type="java.lang.Integer">
             <column name="HOST_OBJECT_ID" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="hostName" type="string">
             <column name="HOST_NAME" length="64" />
        </key-property>
   </composite-id>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Since `hostObjectId` is a nested property have you tried a method definition like: `findByMyEntityHostObjectId`? See the [property expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) section of the Spring Data reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  using property expressions for nested properties like findByMyEntityId_HostObjectId? I am not sure if this will work because embeddable classes id is special case.

Take a look at the examples in the link

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much

it works!!!

```
MyEntity findById_HostObjectId(@Param("hostObjectId") Integer hostObjectId);
```